# Descargar datos de yahoo finance en R

Tags: r, rstudio

¿Como puedo descargar datos de yahoo finance en Rstudio? Me aparece el siguiente error:

> Error in download.file(paste(yahoo.URL, "s=", Symbols.name, "&a=",
>   from.m,  : cannot open URL
>   'https://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csvs=SPY&a=0&b=01&c=2003&d=11&e=31&f=2012&g=d&q=q&y=0&z=SPY&x=.csv'

```
library(quantmod) 
library(xts) 
library(zoo) 
library(TTR) 

## Indice de Referencia IPC 
## Creando un nuevo ambiente 
IPC<- new.env() 
## Obteniendo datos desde yahoo finance 
getSymbols("MXX", env = IPC, src = "yahoo", from = as.Date("2014-10-20"), to = as.Date("2016-10-26")
```

)

Comment: Debes de agregar tu codigo para que te podamos ayudar

Comment: `library(quantmod)`
`library(xts)`
`library(zoo)`
`library(TTR)`
## Indice de Referencia IPC
## Creando un nuevo ambiente
`IPC<- new.env()` 
## Obteniendo datos desde yahoo finance
`getSymbols("^MXX", env = IPC, src = "yahoo", from = as.Date("2014-10-20"), to = as.Date("2016-10-26"))`

Answer (score 1):

Pareciera ser un problema de Yahoo. El error completo es este:

```
    Error in download.file(paste(yahoo.URL, "s=", Symbols.name, "&a=", from.m,  : 
      cannot open URL 'https://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=BAL&a=0&b=01&c=2007&d=4&e=17&f=2017&g=d&q=q&y=0&z=BAL&x=.csv'
    In addition: Warning message:
    In download.file(paste(yahoo.URL, "s=", Symbols.name, "&a=", from.m,  :
      cannot open URL 'https://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=BAL&a=0&b=01&c=2007&d=4&e=17&f=2017&g=d&q=q&y=0&z=BAL&x=.csv': HTTP status was '502 Connection refused'
```

Dónde la parte más interesante dice **`HTTP status was '502 Connection refused'`**. Por otro lado si probás acceder a la url: https://ichart.finance.yahoo.com, vas a tener un linda página que te avisa que estaran de vuelta pronto.

Comment: ***Muchas gracias, saludos***